# Can't map request body json into injected response object

Tags: php, laravel, controller, request

I'm using Laravel 5.4.
I've created a Controller using the cli:

```
$php artisan make:controller --resource
```

I'm implementing then the `store(Request $request)` method this way:

```
public function store(MyCustomObject $request)
{
    return $request;
}
```

I'm using the correct `MyCustomObject` inside the `Controller`, and my custom object is the following:

```
class MyCustomObject 
{
    /** @var string text */
    private $text;

    /**
     * text getter method
     * @return string $text
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * text setter method
     * @param string $text $text
     */
    public function setText(string $text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * toString method
     * @return string class string conversion
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "$this->text";
    }
}
```

I'm then using the following body on the rest client (using application/json content):

```
{"text":"Hello, World!"}
```

But my response is empty, since that json is not mapped into MyCustomObject.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you `dd($request);` before you return?

Comment: `MyCustomObject {#181
  -text: null
}`

Comment: Well, I'd say that's expected since at no point you're setting `$request-> setText()`. What are you trying to accomplish here? I think there's some issue with what you're trying to do vs the approach you're taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with JSON

```
return response()->json($request->all());
```

It will send you back the response as a JSON object. Also, use `$request->all()` or `$request->text`.